# momentJS toNow() and to() to display actual times as opposed to 1 hour or 44 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, momentjs

How do you get momentJS to display things properly? For example

```
runTime = moment(info.timestamp).toNow(true)
```

and

```
runTime = moment(info.timestamp).to(info.timestamp + info.duration, true);
```

is displaying something like

> 23 minutes
>
> OR
>
> 1 hour

The info.timestamp is in epoch.
I just want it to display hours:minutes:seconds

Comment: which statement?

Comment: I want both of those two statements to return as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the [difference](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) if you want to have a custom display. Something like

```
var t1=moment(info.timestamp);
var t2=moment(info.timestamp+info.duration);
var now=moment();

var diff1=moment(now.diff(t1)).format('HH:mm:ss');
var diff2=moment(t2.diff(t1)).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: That's worked fine for the second line of code but what about replacing the toNow()

Comment: you would do something like `moment(moment(info.timestamp).diff(moment())).format('HH:mm:ss')`. Using `moment()` to get the current time

Comment: Thank you! I'm still learning my way around momentJS and that's been a huge help